# Precise analysis of physical interpretations of elliptic

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request, partial-differential-equations, elliptic-equations

When I read Evans' PDE, I find the below content. I am curious about it. Where I can get the precise analysis ?

> [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A probabilistic approach to PDEs comes in the form of Feynman Kac formulae and SDEs (stochastic differential equations). A good text would be [Stochastic Differential Equations-Bernt Øksendal](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3540047581)